# проблема при установке пакета pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

не могу установить pyinstaller

```py
pip install pyinstaller
или
poetry add pyinstaller
```

У меня установлен python 3.11.7

выходит след ошибка:

The current project's supported Python range (>=3.11,<4.0) is not compatible with some of the required packages Python requirement:

- pyinstaller requires Python <3.12,>=3.7, so it will not be satisfied for Python >=3.12,<4.0

Because intelligence-center-umbrella depends on pyinstaller (5.12.0) which requires Python <3.12,>=3.7, version solving failed.

---

> > По идее у меня <3.12 и больше > 3.7 :( все подходит. Использую poetry вместо pip

Answer (score 1):

попробуй переустонавить питон и скачать питон вместе с ним (на офиц сайте питона предлагают скачать пип), это самый быстрый способ